# Exception while trying to read from PubSub in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, publish-subscribe, dataflow

I am using `Apache Beam` 2.18. 
When I run my code in the DirectRunner I can get the messageId and message detail.
However, after I deploy my code to Dataflow, sometimes I get a wrong `messageId`  and the wrong message detail like below.

```
PubsubMessage{message=[123, 34, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 109, 121, 115, 113, 108, 73, 110, 115, 101, 114, 116, -29, -126, -92, -29, -125, -103, -29, -125, -77, -29, -125, -120, 34, 44, 34, 110, 97, 109, 101, 115, 112, 97, 99, 101, 34, 58, 34, 114, 117, 108, 101, 47, -26, -128, -89, -24, -125, -67, -26, -92, -100, -24, -88, -68, -29, -125, -85, -29, -125, -68, -29, -125, -85, 34, 44, 34, 99, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 84, 105, 109, 101], attributes={}, messageId=:"2019-05-20T00:00:00.001","proper}
```

Besides that, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: varint overflow 51498921187342211
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.VarInt.decodeInt(VarInt.java:58)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.readString(StringUtf8Coder.java:55)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.decode(StringUtf8Coder.java:100)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.decode(StringUtf8Coder.java:90)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder.decode(StringUtf8Coder.java:37)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessageWithMessageIdCoder.decode(PubsubMessageWithMessageIdCoder.java:51)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessageWithMessageIdCoder.decode(PubsubMessageWithMessageIdCoder.java:33)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.decode(Coder.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.PubsubReader$PubsubReaderIterator.decodeMessage(PubsubReader.java:129)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillReaderIteratorBase.advance(WindmillReaderIteratorBase.java:57)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillReaderIteratorBase.start(WindmillReaderIteratorBase.java:43)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:361)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:194)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1324)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:151)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1053)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

this is my code get a message from Subscription.

```
PubsubIO.readMessagesWithMessageId().fromSubscription(options.getFromSubscription());
```

I can get a message detail correctly when I used PubsubIO.readString(),
but I also need the messageId.

How can I solve this problem?

Best regards

Comment: Let me clarify your question. 1) Are you running it in DirectRunner? Does it work correctly?
2) What happens when you try to run in DataFlow (GCP)? Can you update your question showing the difference between the data that you get in direct runner and in dataflow?
3) What's this error's context? When it happens? Is it related to your issue?

Hoping to hear from you

Comment: thank you for your response.
when i run it in  DirectRunner, i can get MessagId and correct message.
when i trid to run it in Dataflow,  i got a Exeption like [java.io.IOException: varint overflow 51498921187342211].

the data in DirectRunner
1.messageid:966108514075563
2.the data in Gcp-dataflow
messageid::"2019-05-20T00:00:00.001","proper
when i published a message into topic , that happends

Comment: After carefully reviewing the documentation I'd say that your problem might be a bug. I would advise you to contact the DataFlow support in this link (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=1162867) in order to create an issue.